# Putting props to state in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm working with react-redux in a current project and on my search for react wisdom I came across a 'convention' I don't understand.
Other programmers tend to put a prop to state right in the constructor. Why is that? 
I've never seen it in the official documentation and from there I learned that these two are two different things to hold and share data.
Is there any use in it or mybe just a personal preference?

Thanks.

Comment: which constructor do you mean? In redux, you don't change the constructor of the classes. You work with [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options), which makes any component able to interact with the store. There you provide a `mapStateToProps` function, where you define which parts of the store are used in your component. Is that maybe what you are referring to?

Comment: It wasn't actually about my construcor, but example code from tutorials or stack questions where this was used. These snippets may have not used redux.

Comment: Just because I just stumbled across that situation: I use the constructor in my redux project to read information from query and put them to my store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a pattern for when you need some initial value from outside the component, but then want to either ignore, or not ***immediately*** affect, the outside (by for example dispatching Redux actions on each value change).

For example, maybe you have a form that should be prefilled with some values that the component gets from the outside (Redux state) through `mapStateToProps` or similar. You *could* let every form fields `onChange` dispatch an action that changes the Redux state, causes the incoming props to change, and then re-render the form with the new value. *Or* maybe you find that to be overkill. Maybe you're satisfied with keeping the changing form data in the component internal state until the user actually submits the form, and *only then* dispatch an action that will post the form data, change the Redux state and pass new props (like success status) down to the form component.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, especially when you want to keep things simple by not using `container components` or `flux / redux store` to manage application's state.

A component can manage its own `state`, and the `initialState` will be assigned as the `props` passed from its `parent component`.

Consider the following example:

```
class TodoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // Assign todos property to state so that the TodoList component
    // can self-manage this value without interacting with outside components.
    this.setState({ todos: props.todos }); 
  }

  ...

  addTodo(todoDescription) {
    this.setState({ todos: this.state.todos.concat[todoDescription] });
  }
}
```

However, I still do recommend to separate the `view` components and `data manipulating` components when your applications is complex.

Comment: Your answer is a good addition to jonahe. Yet I accepted his answer as it is a bit more clarifying. Thank you for answering!